# Order of join affects 'extra' column from EXPLAIN / Using Index vs Using Where

Tags: mysql, explain

I have two tables with schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `user_group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_group_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `division_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `office_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dept_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
  KEY `division_id` (`division_id`),
  KEY `office_id` (`office_id`),
  KEY `dept_id` (`dept_id`),
  KEY `division_dept` (`dept_id`,`division_id`),
  KEY `office_dept` (`dept_id`,`office_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is some example data (the actual row count of these tables is around 20,000 and 1,000,000 respectively):

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| group_id | division_id | office_id | dept_id |
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      120 |           1 |        50 |     760 |
|      121 |           1 |        50 |     761 |
|      122 |           1 |        51 |     762 |
|      123 |           2 |        60 |     763 |
|      124 |           2 |        62 |     764 |
|      125 |           2 |        63 |     765 |
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+


+---------------+---------+----------+
| user_group_id | user_id | group_id |
+---------------+---------+----------+
|             1 | 1013410 |      122 |
|             2 | 1020345 |      122 |
|             3 | 1006021 |      125 |
|             4 | 1014809 |      124 |
|             5 | 3117387 |      123 |
|             6 | 3123441 |      125 |
|             7 | 1031113 |      123 |
|             8 | 1024314 |      122 |
|             9 | 1011757 |      120 |
|            10 | 1000795 |      122 |
|            11 | 1003932 |      123 |
|            12 | 3103704 |      120 |
|            13 | 1015192 |      123 |
|            14 | 1005211 |      125 |
|            15 | 1025876 |      120 |
|            16 | 1006252 |      121 |
|            17 | 1006657 |      125 |
|            18 | 1025972 |      125 |
|            19 | 1010517 |      121 |
|            20 | 1001044 |      120 |
|            21 | 1032961 |      123 |
|            22 | 1015185 |      125 |
|            23 | 1018973 |      120 |
|            24 | 1031082 |      120 |
|            25 | 1028828 |      124 |
|            26 | 1024051 |      122 |
|            27 | 1000927 |      120 |
|            28 | 1000608 |      121 |
|            29 | 1004419 |      124 |
|            30 | 1015102 |      124 |
+---------------+---------+----------+
```

Compare the output of `EXPLAIN` for these two queries:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT user_id
FROM `group`
    LEFT JOIN user_group USING (group_id)
WHERE division_id = 2;

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | group      | NULL       | ref  | division_id   | division_id | 4       | const                         |    3 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_group | NULL       | ref  | group_id      | group_id    | 4       | group.group_id                |    5 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+

EXPLAIN
SELECT user_id
FROM user_group
    LEFT JOIN `group` USING (group_id)
WHERE division_id = 2;

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key         | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | group      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,division_id | division_id | 4       | const                         |    3 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_group | NULL       | ref  | group_id            | group_id    | 4       | group.group_id                |    5 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I notice that the order of joins gives me either `Using index` (for the first query) or `Using where; Using index` (for the 2nd).  Everything else about them is nearly identical and based on my data they will always produce the same result set.

**QUESTION:** Why does the second query have the additional `Using Where` condition *and is this a benefit, a detriment, or of no consequence?*

Comment: Different queries lead to different execution plans. The first query is even obfuscated, looking like an outer join, but in your `WHERE` clause you dismiss outer-joined records by forcing `division_id = 2`. If you want a working outer join, then put that criteria in the `ON` clause. If the two queries get you the same output anyhow, why not make this an `INNER JOIN` then (which the first query inofficially already is). In an `INNER JOIN` the order of the tables makes no difference (or if it did it would indicate a flaw in the query optimizer).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Thanks - Actually you're correct in that this should be an `INNER JOIN` - but since there will always be exactly one `group_id` to match a `user_group` row, I don't quite see why it makes a difference - but I suppose it's possible that the 2nd query results in `NULL` values for `group` cells.  Is that why?  The important part of the question though is the very last bit - is the additional `Using where` helping or hurting efficiency?

Comment: I see no foreign key constraint on `group(group_id)`, so the DBMS does not know whether to find a match or not. The first query inner-joins the tables. The second outer-joins the group table. So it just makes no sense to ask whether something the DBMS does for one query and not the other affects performance. These are *different* queries. They can lead to *different* results. So the DBMS handles them differently.

Comment: If there were a foreign key constraint on anything it would be on `user_group.group_id` - but I don't believe MySQL uses them for query optimization.  Anyway, thanks for your input - I'm still unclear on whether `Using where` is a good thing or not.